# How to model updated items with UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: uikit, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I'm struggling to understand how to use `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` to model change of items.

Let's say I have a simple item which looks like this:

```
struct Item {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Based on the names of the generic parameters, `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` should operate not with `Item` itself, but only with identifier, which `Int` in this example.

On the other hand, again based on names of generic parameters, `UICollectionView.CellRegistration` should operate on complete `Item`'s. So my guess is that `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource.CellProvider` is responsible for finding complete `Item's` by id. Which is unfortunate, because then aside from snapshots, I need to maintain a separate storage of items. And there is a risk that this storage may go out of sync with snapshots.

But it is still not clear to me how do I inform `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` that some item changed its `name` without changing its `id`. I want `UICollectionView` to update the relevant cell and animate change in content size, but I don't want insertion or removal animation.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches that would work solve your problem in this scenario.

1. The first is to conform your `Item` model to the hashable protocol. This would allow you to use the entire model as an `identifier`, and the cell provider closure would pass you an object of type `Item`. `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` would use the hash value for each instance of your model (which would consider both the `id` and `name` properties, thereby solving your name changing issue) to identify the data for a cell. This is better than trying to trick the collection view data source into considering only the `id` as the identifier because, as you stated, other aspects of the model might change. The whole point of structs is to act as a value-type, where the composition of all the model's properties determine its 'value'...no need to trick the collection view data source into looking only at `Item.id`.
2. Do as you said, and create a separate dictionary in which you can retrieve the `Item`s based on their id's. While it is slightly more work to maintain a dictionary, it is a fairly trivial difference in terms of lines of code. All you should do is dump and recalculate the dictionary every time you apply a new snapshot. In this case, to update a cell when the model changes, make sure to swap out the model in your dictionary and call `reloadItem` on your snapshot.

While the second option is generally my preferred choice because the point of diffable data source is to allow for the handling of massive data sets by only concerning the data source with a simple identifier for each item, in this case your model is so simple that there's really no concern about wasted compute time calculating hash values, etc. If you think your model is likely to grow over time, I would probably go with the dictionary approach.